# Python do if something will not cause an error

Tags: python, if-statement

I am programming a project, and I need to check if a certain index exists. I was wondering if there was a way to do this using the python `if` statement. I was thinking along the lines of: `if list[100].will_not_cause_error:` any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `list[100]`? Please give details and the code tried.

Comment: please explain better, and put some code

Comment: I know about `try`, but I have a set of code that I want to run if condition a is true, or if a certain index will not cause an error

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way is to try-except this:

```
try:
    do_something(list[100])
except IndexError:
    print("list do not have 100")
```

but if you insist to use `if`, you can test for the length:

```
if len(list) < 101:
   print("list do not have 100")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the length of the list:

```
if len(mylist) > 100):
    # len[100] will be ok to use
```

If this isn't a straight-forward list, you could try to access the index and catch the `IndexError`:

```
try:
    mylist[100]
expect:
    # no index 100 in the list
else:
    # index 100 is OK...
```